# $\sqrt {a \log_{a+b} \sqrt {2a}} + \sqrt {b \log_{a + b} \sqrt {2b}} \le a + b$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have just started learning about logarithms and our teacher gave us some problems for those who want to train for the olympiad. One of them was this inequality
$$ \sqrt {a \log_{a+b} \sqrt {2a}} + \sqrt {b \log_{a + b} \sqrt {2b}} \le a + b$$ with a and b positive real numbers, $a + b \neq 1$.  Since it is my first time working with logarithms, I would like some  general tips on how to deal with them.

Comment: Numbers under radicals may be negatives. It's just wrong. Check please better the given.

Answer (score 1):

Use AM-GM, if $$\log_{a+b} \sqrt{2a} \ge0 \implies \sqrt{2a} \ge 1 \implies a\ge 1/2$$ and similarly $b \ge 1/2$, s.t. $a+b>1$.
Then for
$$\sqrt{a \log_{a+b}\sqrt{2a}} \le \frac{a+\log_{a+b}\sqrt{2a}}{2}~~~(1)$$
$$\sqrt{b \log_{a+b}\sqrt{2b}} \le \frac{b+\log_{a+b}\sqrt{2b}}{2}~~~(2)$$
Adding them we get
$$F=\sqrt{a \log_{a+b}\sqrt{2a}} +\sqrt{b \log_{a+b}\sqrt{2b}} \le \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \log_{a+b} 2\sqrt{ab}$$
Again by AM-GM, we get
$$F\le \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \log_{a+b} (a+b).$$
$$F \le \frac{a+b+1}{2}, s.t. a,b>1/2,  a+b \ne 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Beside the key point raised by @Michael Rozenberg, knowing that there regions where the logarithms can be computed, consider the function
$$f(a,b)=\sqrt {a \log_{a+b} \sqrt {2a}} + \sqrt {b \log_{a + b} \sqrt {2b}} - (a + b)$$ and try to maximize it.

Because of the symmetry, the extremum will correspond to $b=a$; so, we just need to maximize $f(a,a)$. This function starts from $0$ if $a=0$ and cancels for $a=\frac 12$; but it goes through a maximum value of $\frac 14$ at $a=\frac 18$.

In fact, $f(a,b) >0$ if $0 < a, b < \frac 12$

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B-a+-+b+%2B+Sqrt%5B%28a*Log%5BSqrt%5B2%5D*Sqrt%5Ba%5D%5D%29%2FLog%5Ba+%2B+b%5D%5D+%2B+++Sqrt%5B%28b*Log%5BSqrt%5B2%5D*Sqrt%5Bb%5D%5D%29%2FLog%5Ba+%2B+b%5D%5D%3D0.1%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7Bb%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) for the contour line $f(a,b)=0.1$.